# solve Systems of linear inequalities - find point of 2 groups inequalities

Tags: math, linear-algebra

I have 8 inequalities, 4 y>= (dashed lines) and 4 y<= (continous lines). Reading graph I can determine solution area (grey area). For me most interesting is only most right point of solution area. Now i need to do somethig similar but without graph uing only some algorithm. So does exist any methot/algorithm to do that or something similar? Or any other tips how to try find that point mathematically? Ofc image below is only example, I'm looking for method, not solution of this example.

[inequalities  graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsHMo.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: for questions about maths you can try https://math.stackexchange.com/